# Python: Using For Loops to Create New Columns using Conditional If Statements

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to create the following data frame using for loops.  Below is the table I want to output with purple highlighting the fields I want to create.

[image]

Below is the code I wrote.  When I run it nothing happens.  The three columns I'm looking for "Revenue Segment", "Expenses Segment", and "Profit Segment" do not get created.  There is no error log either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
regions = ['East', 'Central', 'West', 'Midwest']
target_var = ['Revenue', 'Expenses', 'Profit']

output_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in regions:
    for v in target_var: 

        # Create Counter
        temp_df_1 = df_HA_noHA_append_5[df_HA_noHA_append_5['Region'] == i]
        temp_df_1['Counter'] = range(len(temp_df_1))
        temp_df_1['Counter_2'] = temp_df_1['Counter'] + 1

        # Split 
        temp_df_1_AUM_min = temp_df_1[v].min()
        percentile_value = 0.99
        temp_df_1_AUM_max = temp_df_1[v].quantile(percentile_value)

        # Cuts 
        No_Cuts = 3 

        # Intervals 
        Intervals = temp_df_1_AUM_max / No_Cuts


        # Create Interval Table 
        Interval_Min = [temp_df_1_AUM_min, Intervals, Intervals*2]
        Interval_Max = [Intervals, Intervals*2, temp_df_1_AUM_max]
        Segment = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']    


        # Dataframe
        df_Intervals = pd.DataFrame({'Interval_Min': Interval_Min, 'Interval_Max': Interval_Max, 'Segment': Segment})
        df_Intervals = df_Intervals[['Interval_Min', 'Interval_Max', 'Segment']]


        # Create Segments 
        Segment = []

        # Loop through the AUM 12_MONTH SNAPSHOT column 

        for i in temp_df_1[v]:
            if i >= df_Intervals.iloc[0, 0] and i <= df_Intervals.iloc[0, 1]:
                Segment.append(df_Intervals.iloc[0, 2])
            elif i > df_Intervals.iloc[1, 0] and i <= df_Intervals.iloc[1, 1]:
                Segment.append(df_Intervals.iloc[1, 2])
            elif i > df_Intervals.iloc[2, 0]:
                Segment.append(df_Intervals.iloc[2, 2])
            else:
                Segment.append('')

            # print (df_Intervals)


        # Append list to new column 

        temp_df_1[v] = Segment


        output_df = output_df.append(temp_df_1)
```

Comment: Have you walked through the code to figure out where the unexpected result originates?